# Time for another chat session?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Now that the holidays are over, I think it's an opportune time to hold another chat session to discuss site promotion, and perhaps other issues that we think are important. Let's schedule and run it along similar lines to [the first one](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237/how-about-a-chat-session-to-discuss-site-promotion). I'll post an answer to suggest a time. If you would attend at that time, upvote it; if you have a conflict, downvote it and suggest a different time in a new answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First suggestion: Monday, January 10, at 8:00 PM GMT (3:00 PM US Eastern time).

Comment: There seem to be no objections so far, so I'm going with this.